# I want to change the value of 'is_active' change 1 or 0 in my database using jquery, Here is my code

Tags: php, jquery

Here is button image value

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE is_active=0");

echo "<div class='row'>

              <div class='col-lg-12'>

                <table class='table table-striped table-advance table-hover'>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th><i class='icon_profile'></i> First Name</th>
                      <th><i class='icon_calendar'></i> DOB</th>
                      <th><i class='icon_mail_alt'></i> Email</th>
                      <th><i class='icon_pin_alt'></i> Country</th>
                      <th><i class='icon_mobile'></i> Mobile</th>
                      <th><i class='icon_cogs'></i> Action</th>
                    </tr>";
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                      echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row['dob'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row['country_livingin'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row['mobile'] . "</td>";
                      echo"<td>
                        <div class='btn-group'>
                          <a id='pending' class='imgicon btn btn-success' href='#'><i id='check' class='icon_check_alt2'></i></a> 
                        </div>
                      </td>";
                      echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                    mysqli_close($con);
                ?>
```

Jquery

```
$(".imgicon").on("click",function()
{

 // alert("button");

var parent = $(this).parents("tr");

var dataEmail = $(parent).find("td:nth-child(3)").text();

        $.ajax({
         url:'pending_method.php',
         dataType:'json',
         data:{email:dataEmail},
         success:function(data){
            alert('hi')
          },
          error:function(data){
            alert("error");
          }

        });

    });
```

pending_method.php

```
<?php
        // $con=mysqli_connect("166.62.6.65","UBBS_Matrimonial","UBBS_Matrimonial","UBBS_Matrimonial");

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Dummy");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        var email = $_POST["email"];
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE customer set is_active=1 WHERE email=email);
?>
```

Comment: Is there any problem while you trying to run this script? What have you tried so far? This column `is_active` is bit type?

Comment: Yes, It is bit type

Comment: yeah
its going into error part ..

Comment: I want each value one by one change into database

Comment: What kind of error are you having when you try to UPDATE (or before that)?

Comment: its goes on Error part ...

Comment: and if i try from another method then it was successfully but all values of is_active changed.

Comment: look at this line `var email = $_POST["email"];`. It is not seems to be a request POST Ajax in your JQuery.

Comment: Yep, but i am not able to do thiss

Comment: Why not? You can do this :).  Just add the following property inside your $.ajax: `method: 'POST'` and see what happen

Comment: yes, i am talking about the chat option.

Comment: Surely i update the method in to post

Comment: It is also not working bro ...

Comment: Well. I guess you are having a syntax error. Look at this line now: `$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE customer set is_active=1 WHERE email=email);`. You forgot to close quote inside your SQL Statement.

Comment: Hmmm, but not working

Comment: Alright. Now change this line `var email = $_POST["email"];` to `$email = $_POST["email"];` and change this other line `$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE customer set is_active=1 WHERE email=email);` to `$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE customer set is_active=1 WHERE email=".$email);` and check what will happen

Comment: Not working 
error in to $email = $_POST["email"];

Comment: which error are you facing it?